# Conditional operator weird output

Tags: c++, boolean, conditional-operator

I used to belive that using conditional operator in statement like this below is OK, but it is not. Is there any circumscription to use conditional operator in complex statement?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int a = 1;
    int b = 10;
    bool c = false;

    int result = a * b + b + c ? b : a;

    std::cout << result << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Predicted output : `21`

Actual output : `10`

Why?

Comment: Order of operators matter.

Comment: Yeah. I just check with `()` :|

Comment: ?: operator has the second lowest precedence of all.

Comment: Yes. `:` is somewhat special, its more like a separator. Once parser finds `?` operator, anything between `?` and `:` is always a true block for `?` operator and rest after `:` is false block.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The initializer in this declaration

```
int result = a * b + b + c ? b : a;
```

is equivalent to

```
int result = ( a * b + b + c ) ? b : a;
```

The subexpression `a * b + b + c`  evaluates to `20`. As it is not equal to 0 then it is contextually converted to `true`.

So the value of the conditional expression is the second subexpression that is `b` which is equal to 10.

I think you mean the following initializer in the declaration

```
int result = a * b + b + ( c  ? b : a );
```

Answer (score 4):

The expression `a * b + b + c ? b : a` is *grouped* as

```
(a * b + b + c) ? b : a
```

which accounts for the result being `b`. Note also that `c` is implicitly converted to an `int` with value `0`.